# AirPods Double tap to Pause not working when player playback rate > 1.0

Tags: ios, avfoundation, airpods

I have an `AVPlayer` playing audio in my app. I've registered to handle remote commands via `MPRemoteCommandCenter`, including Play, Pause, Stop, TogglePlayPause, and ChangePlaybackRate.

However, whenever my AVPlayer is playing back at a rate that is greater than 1.0, (say, 1.15x), when the AirPods are double-tapped my app gets a command of `play`, even when the  app is already playing. If the app is playing back audio at a rate of 1.0 or less, I receive a `pause` remote command, as expected.

Update: It looks like this is related to what the value of `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` is set to. When that value is 1.0 or less, pause works properly. When it's over 1.0, pause does not get called, play does. If I forcefully set the value of MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate in the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` infoDict to 1.0, everything works as expected.